# Bootstrap: Make height of div 100% despite navbar (in order to center text)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5. I'm trying to get the text in the middle of the page vertically centered. In order to do that, I needed to get the container of the div to take up 100% of the page. I tried using h-100 to do that, but due to the navbar taking up some height, it caused an overflow. I just want the div with the text in it to take up the remaining vertical height, or somehow center the text without needing to do 100% height.

I'm not using any user-defined CSS except for some color & font customizations.

[image: A scrollbar is present.]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="./css/overrides.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.png">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="h-100" style="background:url('./images/test_bg.jpeg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:fit;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top mt-auto">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo_desktop.png" width="200"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="h-100 container-fluid my-auto d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center classes">
        <div class="row text-light">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h1 class="display-1">IF YOU CAN THINK IT,<br />WE CAN MAKE IT.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fixed-top` instead of `sticky-top`. The difference is between being in the flow of the document or out of it.

Edit: on mobile you'd still want it to be sticky probably. So use a media query to distinguish the position.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="./css/overrides.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="./images/favicon.png">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body class="h-100" style="background:url('./images/test_bg.jpeg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:fit;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top mt-auto">
    <div class="mx-auto text-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo_desktop.png" width="200"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="h-100 container-fluid my-auto d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center classes">
    <div class="row text-light">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="display-1">IF YOU CAN THINK IT,<br />WE CAN MAKE IT.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! On another note, though, if my navbar wasn't fixed, just a navbar that is at the top of the page and that's it. How would I go about doing the same thing as in the question? (Centering the text/giving the div a full height)?

Comment: `position:absolute`  would also take the element out of the flow. Also `float` but I think that's it.

Comment: But wouldn't ```position: absolute``` ruin some of bootstrap's properties?

Comment: Maybe need to adjust width to 100% or something similar. Are you referring to mobile menu or just generally speaking?

Comment: Yes, mobile menu, the collapse button's position overlapped the navbar brand when I tried using absolute positioning earlier today.

Comment: You could make the div itself absolute, or set a negative `margin-bottom:-56px`  for the navbar with the height of it.